Bare project of react native not running on Mac
ng, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'hermes-engine' from project 'Pods')
warning: Run script build phase 'Bundle React Native code and images' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'demo' from project 'demo')
warning: Run script build phase '[CP-User] [RN]Check rncore' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'React-Fabric' from project 'Pods')

--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:48DE8EFA-7939-4AFC-9EA0-28F59C2AF10D, OS:17.4, name:iPhone 12 min ios 17.4 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:48DE8EFA-7939-4AFC-9EA0-28F59C2AF10D, OS:17.4, name:iPhone 12 min ios 17.4 }
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /Users/atharvasonawane/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/demo-gemuwpfsyomrgccujyopmbzckjal/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-Codegen.build/Script-46EB2E00012A80.sh (in target 'React-Codegen' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)


created a new project and tried to run it and its showing this error
I want to make react native run on Mac buts it not running tried 3-4times --force uninstalling and installing the node

so does /Documents/React exist? the error is telling you a path is configured wrong.

Please share the whole output you get

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
